# Protobuf-net how to copy a RuntimeTypeModel into another?

Tags: protobuf-net

Context of the question: I need to modify a `RuntimeTypeModel` instance to add new subtypes, but after a serializer has been created and used already. I read from other questions that the model cannot be changed once a serializer is already created, so I thought I would just create a new model, copy over the information from the old one, and then modify the new one. But I am not sure how to do the copying properly...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What features do you need to copy? For example, are the fields just whatever was defined in attributes and you want to copy just the sub-types (those being less well known)? Or...?

Comment: Mostly subtypes...The application I have need to serialize derives classes D1 and D2, say, but the assemblies are loaded at different times. So currently first D1 is added as a subtype, and some code is executed which serialize/deserializes D1. Then, I implemented a handler of the AssemblyLoad event to let the protobuf know about D2 when it is used, but this triggers an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that you're talking about cloning the sub-type definitions; one way to do this would be something like:

```cs
// given "RuntimeTypeModel oldModel", "MetaType newMetaType" and "Type dataType"
if (oldModel.IsDefined(dataType))
{
    var oldSubTypes = oldModel[dataType].GetSubtypes();
    foreach (var subType in oldSubTypes)
    {
        newMetaType.AddSubType(subType.FieldNumber, subType.DerivedType.Type);
    }
    // TODO: add the new sub-types here
}
```

Note that in your case it *may* make more sense to store these definitions somewhere *external* to protobuf-net when needed, and fetch them from *there* rather than having to retain the old model. In either case, I recommend using the `AfterApplyDefaultBehaviour` callback, which will make it easier to avoid timing complications (this allows you to hook into the code that happens inside the library when types are discovered):

```cs
newModel.AfterApplyDefaultBehaviour += (sender, args) =>
{
    var dataType = args.Type;
    var newMetaType = args.MetaType;
    // your code to apply the sub-types here, perhaps from the above
};
```

---

I should emphasise, however, that "knowing the sub-types earlier" is a much simpler solution to this scenario, even if it means loading assemblies earlier. If you're going to load them *anyway*, deferring them seems to be complicating the code.

Comment: Thanks! I should say the reason why I couldn't know all the sub-types beforehand is that the codebase is constantly adding new serializable subtypes and new assemblies which use these subtypes. So this approach to use the RuntimeTypeModel is for reducing the workload of registering all these types to protobuf, which as I understand can be a lot of added code...? If you have some ideas about how I could make this easier with protobuf-net please let me know!